# How to show SoftPhone layout into a custom VisualForce page?

Tags: visualforce, community, dynamic-visualforce, softphone

I have a custom visual force page with a form to create a new lead when any new client call. The softphone call record is showing into left side of any pages in my salesforce environment, except into my new custom visualforce page, that is a problem i want show that component (softphone) in this visualforce page or any other visualforce pages that i want to create.
thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Enable sidebar in custom pages then it will diaplay in sidebar. Othwise you cn use same component which you have in your sidebar

Comment: @TusharSharma - I have enabled the sidebar on my VF page and getting the same result.